# Record print statements during running a program in SLURM

Tags: python, slurm

I am running a python program on SLURM and I get the print statements only after the run is complete. I want to save the print statements in output file during the running.

I tried the solutions from [this link](http://How%20do%20I%20save%20print%20statements%20when%20running%20a%20program%20in%20SLURM?), but did not work in my case. One solution was to use `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print()` and the other was to start python interpreter with `-u` option. I am using python 2.7. Does anyone have any idea?